# How to install nvidia driver (gt 755m) on Fedora 20?

Tags: linux, fedora, nvidia

I am trying to install nvidia drivers for my Geforce GT755M on Fedora 20. I tried installing kmod, akmod and compiled from source. None of them seem to work. I always end up at a black screen.

After compiling from source, when I reboot the system, I can not get to the login screen. Here's the output of Xorg.0.log:

```
 [   941.731] 
X.Org X Server 1.14.4
Release Date: 2013-10-31
[   941.731] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   941.731] Build Operating System:  3.14.3-200.fc20.x86_64 
[   941.731] Current Operating System: Linux abhay-mittal 3.14.5-200.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 2 14:26:34 UTC 2014 x86_64
[   941.731] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.14.5-200.fc20.x86_64 root=UUID=9508d200-f5fd-4a84-8ceb-549c1eb548d6 ro vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
[   941.731] Build Date: 14 May 2014  12:35:26AM
[   941.731] Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.14.4-9.fc20 
[   941.731] Current version of pixman: 0.30.0
[   941.731]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   941.731] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   941.731] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Jun 11 18:57:29 2014
[   941.731] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   941.731] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   941.731] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   941.732] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[   941.732] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[   941.732] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[   941.732] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[   941.732] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[   941.732] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[   941.732] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   941.732] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   941.732] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   941.732] (**) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1,
    catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d,
    built-ins
[   941.732] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
[   941.732] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[   941.732] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[   941.732] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[   941.732] (II) Loader magic: 0x80dd00
[   941.732] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   941.732]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   941.732]    X.Org Video Driver: 14.1
[   941.732]    X.Org XInput driver : 19.2
[   941.732]    X.Org Server Extension : 7.0
[   941.732] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[   941.935] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   941.936] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0416:17aa:3801 rev 6, Mem @ 0xc2000000/4194304, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   941.936] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:0fcd:17aa:3801 rev 161, Mem @ 0xc0000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, 0xa0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[   941.936] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[   941.936] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[   941.936] (WW) "xwayland" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[   941.936] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   941.936] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[   941.936] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[   941.936] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module glamoregl
[   941.936] (II) UnloadModule: "glamoregl"
[   941.936] (II) Unloading glamoregl
[   941.936] (EE) Failed to load module "glamoregl" (module does not exist, 0)
[   941.936] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   941.936] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   941.944] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   941.944]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   941.944]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   941.944] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  331.79  Sat May 17 23:58:32 PDT 2014
[   941.944] Loading extension GLX
[   941.944] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   941.944] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[   941.944] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   941.944]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   941.944]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   941.944] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  331.79  Sat May 17 23:37:42 PDT 2014
[   941.944] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[   941.944] (++) using VT number 1

[   941.944] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   941.944] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   941.944] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   941.945] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   941.945]    compiled for 1.14.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   941.945]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   941.945] (WW) Unresolved symbol: fbGetGCPrivateKey
[   941.945] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[   941.945] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[   941.945] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[   941.945] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   941.945]    compiled for 1.14.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   941.945]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   941.945] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[   941.945] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[   941.945] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[   941.969] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module. Please check your
[   941.969] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages.
[   941.969] (EE) No devices detected.
[   941.969] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   941.969] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   941.969] (EE) 
Please consult the Fedora Project support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   941.969] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   941.969] (EE)
```

I've looked at posts on various forums, and found no working solution. Can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: Why not use the official binary from the nvidia website?

Comment: I have tried that SkyDan. The output of Xorg.0.log is the one that I get after installing binary.

And as soon as I uninstall nvidia, everything seems to work fine again.

Comment: Okay, can you show the kernel log of about the same time period as this log? It's in /var/log/kern.log

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Notebook (755M indicates this is a possibility), if you've got an 'integrated' Intel graphics chipset, then a clean way to go is with "BumbleBee".

Installing the nvidia module from source (or via kmod/akmod) was a painful experience for me : Most likely because I had UEFI on, and the module needed to be signed - and that is another matter entirely.  I went with disabling Secure Boot.

The nice thing about Bumblebee is that it allows NVidia's Optimus stuff to be applicable in Linux, meaning that you can operate in 'low power' mode when you don't need the full nvidia GPU.

The Fedora installation instructions are here : https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bumblebee#fedora20

And my blow-by-blow account is here : http://mdda.net/oss-blog/2014-06/install-nvidia-optimus-on-FC20-acer-notebook/